# Getting custom MSBuild property of a DTE VCConfiguration project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, envdte

The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCConfiguration` interface is rather poor and does not expose all the properties of a project. How do I get a custom MSBuild property via the DTE interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, simply invoke VCConfiguration.Evaluate. For example, `VCConfiguration.Evaluate("$(ConfigurationType)")`.

Retrieving `VCConfiguration` can be done in any of the many ways. Here's an example written in VB.NET to make your life harder:

`DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects(0).Object.Configurations.Item(1).Evaluate("$(ConfigurationType)")`